# How to create a nested dictionary from a normal dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the input json list of dictionaries like below:

```
data1 = 
{
  {
    "nm": "Oliver Cromwell",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "Commonwealth",
    "yrs": "1653-1658"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Richard Cromwell",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "Commonwealth",
    "yrs": "1658-1659"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Charles II",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Stuart",
    "yrs": "1660-1685"
  },...
```

I want to create a nested dictionary like below:

```
 dic={"United Kingdom”:   {
  "House of Blois” : [“Stephen”],
  'yrs': '1135-1154'}
```

I followed this logic but it has a funtional bug:

```
dic={}
i=0
while i<len(data):
    for k,v in data[i].items():
        if data[i]['cty'] not in dic:
            dic[data[i]["cty"]]={}
        if data[i]['hse'] not in dic[data[i]['cty']]:
            dic[data[i]['cty']][data[i]['hse']] = []
            dic[data[i]['cty']][data[i]['hse']].append(data[i]['nm'])
            dic['yrs']=data[i]['yrs']
i+=1
```

But it's not complete: this is the output.

```
{'United Kingdom': {'Commonwealth': ['Commonwealth'],
                    'House of Angevin': ['Henry II'],
                    'House of Blois': ['Stephen'],
                    'House of Denmark': ['Cnut'],
                    'House of Hanover': ['George I'],
                    'House of Lancaster': ['Henry IV'],
                    'House of Normandy': ['William I'],
                    'House of Orange': ['William III'],
                    'House of Plantagenet': ['Henry III'],
                    'House of Saxe-Coburg-Gotha': ['Edward VII'],
                    'House of Stuart': ['James I'],
                    'House of Tudor': ['Henry VII'],
                    'House of Wessex': ['Edmund lronside'],
                    'House of Windsor': ['George V'],
                    'House of York': ['Edward IV']
                   }
 'yrs': '1910-1936'}
```

Comment: Your second example isn't valid syntax.

Comment: What are the other possible items of the `data1` dictionary? Some more examples would help. Do you have a list of dictionaries?

Comment: all data1 items are like:   {'cty': 'United Kingdom',
 'hse': 'House of Blois',
 'nm': 'Stephen',
 'yrs': '1135-1154'}

Comment: Again, is it a list of dictionaries? If so, please add the complete example in the quesiton.

Comment: Please show us the expected result for the example data you gave - `data1`.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how directory iteration works.  You're trying to holistically grab the entire dictionary at once, but the language semantics give you only `key, value` pairs.

```
for data1['cty'], data1['hse'], data1['nm'] , data1['yrs'] in data1:
```

Is wrong.  The way you would iterate is more like this:

```
for key, val in data1:
```

And the you get the four items in some order, such as:

```
'cty', 'United Kingdom'
'hse', 'House of Blois'
'nm',  'Stephen'
'yrs', '1135-1154'
```

on four consecutive iterations.

The way you've presented this, your four entries are entirely independent: you can't depend on the order (with a common dict).

To help you with a full solution, you'll have to show us two or three records, so we can figure out how to iterate through them.

Comment: yea, you are right, let me try it. for k,v in data1.items()  right?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't think this is *quite* what you want.  Please expand your posted example to include at least two nations in your input dict.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new dictionary of house groupings for each country, you can use a recursive solution with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data1=[{"nm": "Oliver Cromwell", "cty": "United Kingdom", "hse":"Commonwealth","yrs": "1653-1658"},{"nm": "Richard Cromwell", "cty": "United Kingdom", "hse": "Commonwealth","yrs": "1658-1659"}, {"nm": "Charles II", "cty": "United Kingdom", "hse": "House of Stuart","yrs": "1660-1685"}]
def group(data, path):
  current = next(path, None)
  return data if not current else {a:group([{c:d for c, d in i.items() if c != current} for i in b], path) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[current]), key=lambda x:x[current])}

print(group(data1, iter(['cty', 'hse'])))
```

Output:

```
{'United Kingdom': {'Commonwealth': [{'nm': 'Oliver Cromwell', 'yrs': '1653-1658'}, {'nm': 'Richard Cromwell', 'yrs': '1658-1659'}], 'House of Stuart': [{'nm': 'Charles II', 'yrs': '1660-1685'}]}}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Your answer is perfect. Could you please expand it or explain what's happening in the function. Thank you.

Comment: @user8910400 Glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I accept your answer. Could you please expand it or explain what's happening in the function. Thank you.